# Python / Pandas - Turning a list with inner dictionaries into a DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and I need to turn a list with inner dictionaries into a DataFrame

Below an example of the list:

```
[('Fwd1', {'Score': 1.0, 'Prediction': 7.6, 'MAPE': 2.37}), ('Fwd2', {'Score': 1.0, 'Prediction': 7.62, 'MAPE': 2.57}), ('Fwd3', {'Score': 1.0, 'Prediction': 7.53, 'MAPE': 2.54})]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
        Prediction    MAPE    Score                                               
Date                                                     
Fwd1           7.6    2.37        1
Fwd2          7.62    2.57        1
Fwd3          7.53    2.54        1
```

Anyone available to enlight my journey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `list` of `tuples` into `dict` first and then create a dataframe. Unfortunately, in this structure, the index and columns need to be swapped for you desired output, so you need to transpose it.

Assume `x` is your list:

```
In [18]: dict(x)
Out[18]:
{'Fwd1': {'MAPE': 2.37, 'Prediction': 7.6, 'Score': 1.0},
 'Fwd2': {'MAPE': 2.57, 'Prediction': 7.62, 'Score': 1.0},
 'Fwd3': {'MAPE': 2.54, 'Prediction': 7.53, 'Score': 1.0}}

In [19]: pd.DataFrame(dict(x))
Out[19]:
            Fwd1  Fwd2  Fwd3
MAPE        2.37  2.57  2.54
Prediction  7.60  7.62  7.53
Score       1.00  1.00  1.00

In [20]: pd.DataFrame(dict(x)).T
Out[20]:
      MAPE  Prediction  Score
Fwd1  2.37        7.60      1
Fwd2  2.57        7.62      1
Fwd3  2.54        7.53      1
```

Comment: Outstanding. All I need now is to change the order of the columns so "Prediction" is the first one. Do you know how could I do that?

Comment: Python dictionary does not guarantee order. That's why the columns have different order than what appears in dictionary. You can reorder columns as df=df[['Prediction', 'MAPE','Score']]

Comment: Great, that's what I needed